# How to convert Json packet in Java script

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I have a device which is sending data as JSON object as below, Would anyone help to convert that data into key/value pair by using Javascript as I am not very good in JS.

Below is the packet I am recieving.

2022-10-16 07:41:20,348 {
"IsForward": false,
"Name": "IgnitionOn",
"Fields": [
{
"Type": "signedint",
"Name": "Latitude",
"Value": "5460000"
},
{
"Type": "signedint",
"Name": "Longitude",
"Value": "10860000"
},
{
"Name": "Speed",
"Value": "0"
},
{
"Name": "Heading",
"Value": "361"
},
{
"Name": "EventTime",
"Value": "1665906013"
},
{
"Name": "GpsFixAge",
"Value": "1023"
},
{
"Name": "IsIgnitionOn",
"Value": "true"
},
{
"Name": "Odometer",
"Value": "0"
},
{
"Name": "CellStatus",
"Value": "ServerConnected"
},
{
"Name": "CellRoamingList",
"Value": "White"
},
{
"Name": "CellRssi",
"Value": "10"
}
],
"SIN": 254,
"MIN": 4
}

Comment: that's what [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) exists for

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `JSON.parse()` for example `JSON.parse(packet)`

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(json) is used to convert JSON to Javascript objects/arrays and JSON.stringify(objects) can convert normal JS objects/arrays to JSON...